# riak and atomic increments

Tags: nosql, riak

I use redis for frond end web app back but for backend I want to use riak but is not clear if it supports eventual consistency with atomic increments.  I would like to do counters but does not have to be as fast as redis.  If riak cannot do it, who can?  Besides redis of course.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. There is no way for us to lock a riak key-value pair in order to prevent other processes from incrementing at the same time. Use a different product.

Answer (score 0):

Riak does support atomic commits, but only for a single key/value. What you need to bear in mind is that when you write to Riak you're writing to a cluster that is eventually consistent. There is a chance that you're going to write a value to one node at the same time that something else is writing a value to the same location in another node. Assuming that `allow_mult` is set to `true` on the bucket, this will result in a conflict at *read* time which will need to be resolved by your application.